# exchange server

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

i have a exchange 2003 server (iss 6.0)

i wanne make that if i go to h t t p : / / locahost/exchange that i will be redirected to h t t p s : / / localhost/exchange

but i have screwwed it up a little bit.

when i go to  h t t p : / / localhost/exchange i get :

Secure Channel Required
This Virtual Directory requires a browser that supports the configured encryption options.

(i use latest version of firefox)

when i go to h t t p s : / / localhost/exchange i get connecion got interrupted...

somebody any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these articles.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839357

http://raoulpop.com/2007/08/07/automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https/